# Lists & arrays c#

Tags: c#, arrays, list

**Hello**

I am doing a logbook, where there is a menu of different options. In menu 1, the user enters his post (Title and Post). In Menu 2 you will be able to view all saved posts. You should therefore be able to see ALL posts that have been written, but the only one shown is the last written post. Does anyone know how to solve this?

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<string[]> loggBok = new List<string[]> {};
    string[] post = new string[2];
    post[0] = "Titel";
    post[1] = "Inlägg";
    DateTime tiden = DateTime.Now;
    Console.WriteLine(tiden);
    bool isRunning = true;

    while (isRunning)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\n\tVälkommen till loggboken!");
        Console.WriteLine("\t[1]Skriv ett inlägg: ");
        Console.WriteLine("\t[2]Skriv ut alla inlägg");
        Console.WriteLine("\t[3]Sök inlägg");
        Console.WriteLine("\t[4]Avsluta programmet!");
        Console.Write("\nVälj meny: ");

        int nr;
        int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out nr);
        switch (nr)
        {
            case 1:
                Console.WriteLine("Skriv en titel till ditt inlägg: ");
                post[0] = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Skriv ett inlägg: ");
                post[1] = Console.ReadLine();
                loggBok.Add(post);
                break;
            case 2:
                foreach (string[] text in loggBok)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nHär är dina inlägg i loggboken:\n ");
                    Console.WriteLine("Inlägg:{0} " + "\n\t{1}", text);
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                Console.WriteLine("Skriv in ett ord för att söka bland dina inlägg");
                string keyword = Console.ReadLine();
                foreach (string[] text in loggBok)
                {
                    if (post[0].Contains(keyword) || post[1].Contains(keyword))
                    {
                        Console.Write("\nTitel: " + post[0] + "\n" + post[1]);
                    }
                }
                break;
            case 4:
                isRunning = false;
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Försök igen, välj mellan 1-4!");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a bug here, I think: `Console.WriteLine("Inlägg:{0} " + "\n\t{1}", text);`. Since text is an array, you should reference the indexes `0` for title and `1` for post: `Console.WriteLine("Inlägg:{0} " + "\n\t{1}", text[0], text[1]);`

Comment: Also, it looks like this line should be outside of the `foreach` loop, so it only prints once instead of once for every post: `Console.WriteLine("\nHär är dina inlägg i loggboken:\n ");`

Comment: `string[] post = new string[2];` should be moved under `case1` so you create a new post each time

Comment: In `case 3:` you are using `text` for your loop condition, but referencing `post` in the loop body. You should replace `post` with `text`

Answer (score 1):

You only ever create one `post`:

```
string[] post = new string[2];
```

That's at the top of `Main`, and you never replace it.

Every time you "add a post", you assign new values to that same array and add *the same array object* to the list all over again, so the list has many references to the same array object.

Instead, create a new array object for each new post:

```
case 1:
    post = new string[2];

    Console.WriteLine("Skriv en titel till ditt inlägg: ");
    post[0] = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Skriv ett inlägg: ");
    post[1] = Console.ReadLine();
    loggBok.Add(post);
    break;
```

Answer (score 1):

I posted some comments under your code, here are the fixes:

You can move your input validation to the initial point where the user is entering the value, so you don't have to write out the full menu each time. This also means you can get rid of the `default` case, since we know the input is a number from 1 to 4:

```
int nr;
while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out nr) || nr < 1 || nr > 4)
{
    Console.Write("Försök igen, välj mellan 1-4: ");
}
```

In `case 1:`, the line: `string[] post = new string[2];` should be moved under `case1` so you create a new post each time:

```
case 1:
    Console.WriteLine("Skriv en titel till ditt inlägg: ");
    string[] post = new string[2];
    // rest of code omitted...
```

In `case 2:`, it looks like this line should be outside of the `foreach` loop, so it only prints once instead of once for every post:

```
case 2:
    Console.WriteLine("\nHär är dina inlägg i loggboken:\n ");
    foreach (string[] text in loggBok)
    // rest of code omitted...
```

Also in `case 2:`, you have a bug here, I think: `Console.WriteLine("Inlägg:{0} " + "\n\t{1}", text);`. Since `text` is an array, you should reference the indexes `0` for title and `1` for post:

```
foreach (string[] text in loggBok)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Inlägg:{0} " + "\n\t{1}", text[0], text[1]);
    // rest of code omitted...
```

In `case 3:`, you are using `text` for your loop condition, but referencing `post` in the loop body. You should replace `post` with `text`:

```
case 3:
    Console.WriteLine("Skriv in ett ord för att söka bland dina inlägg");
    string keyword = Console.ReadLine();
    foreach (string[] text in loggBok)
    {
        if (text[0].Contains(keyword) || text[1].Contains(keyword))
        {
            Console.Write("\nTitel: " + text[0] + "\n" + text[1]);
        }
    }
    break;
```

All together, the changes would look like:

```
private static void Main()
{
    List<string[]> loggBok = new List<string[]> {};
    DateTime tiden = DateTime.Now;
    Console.WriteLine(tiden);
    bool isRunning = true;

    while (isRunning)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\n\tVälkommen till loggboken!");
        Console.WriteLine("\t[1]Skriv ett inlägg: ");
        Console.WriteLine("\t[2]Skriv ut alla inlägg");
        Console.WriteLine("\t[3]Sök inlägg");
        Console.WriteLine("\t[4]Avsluta programmet!");
        Console.Write("\nVälj meny: ");

        int nr;
        while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out nr) || nr < 1 || nr > 4)
        {
            Console.Write("Försök igen, välj mellan 1-4: ");
        }

        switch (nr)
        {
            case 1:
                Console.WriteLine("Skriv en titel till ditt inlägg: ");
                string[] post = new string[2];
                post[0] = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Skriv ett inlägg: ");
                post[1] = Console.ReadLine();
                loggBok.Add(post);
                break;
            case 2:
                Console.WriteLine("\nHär är dina inlägg i loggboken:\n ");
                foreach (string[] text in loggBok)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Inlägg:{0} " + "\n\t{1}", text[0], text[1]);
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                Console.WriteLine("Skriv in ett ord för att söka bland dina inlägg");
                string keyword = Console.ReadLine();
                foreach (string[] text in loggBok)
                {
                    if (text[0].Contains(keyword) || text[1].Contains(keyword))
                    {
                        Console.Write("\nTitel: " + text[0] + "\n" + text[1]);
                    }
                }
                break;
            case 4:
                isRunning = false;
                break;
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("\nDone!\nPress any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`post` is a reference type, That means that you're adding a reference to it when you add it to `loggBok`, the value doesn't get copied

You can solve this by instantiating a new `string[]` in case 1:

```
post = new string[2];
Console.WriteLine("Skriv en titel till ditt inlägg: ");
...
```